# Is the derivative of the sigmoid function always the same regardless of its inner variables?

Tags: algorithm, math, neural-network, conv-neural-network

The derivative of the sigmoid function is:

```
df(sigmoid(x)) = sigmoid(x) ( 1 - sigmoid (x))
```

Is this always true no matter what 'x' is? I'm calculating a back propagation of a CNN by hand and it seems that way with my output function being sigmoid solving for the gradients W0, P, etc.

Thank you.

Comment: Perhaps you need to remind yourself of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule

Comment: This is true of the logistic function, but not sigmoid functions in general. The logistic function is the solution of the first-order differential equation: **f′(x) = f(x)(1 - f(x))**. Note that this does not mean that the derivative of the logistic function is constant, i.e., "always the same regardless of its inner variables." The derivative is clearly a function of **x**.